# Can I prevent a program from opening my browser and sending me to a web page when I uninstall it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, uninstall

It really annoys me when I uninstall a program only to find that its last act of crappiness is to open my web browser and send me to some page to answer questions about why the app is so crappy that I had to uninstall it.

How can I disable this functionality? I'm uninstalling it because it sucks, I don't want it to take over my browser during its death throes!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you can do about it. An (un)installer generally runs with Administrator rights, because it needs access to `C:\Program Files\`. It therefore has freedom to do pretty much what it wants.

Answer (score 1):

You could unplug or disable your ethernet adapter before running the uninstaller.  It will still try to pull up a web page, but it just won't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Just a quick update ; < " i found a solid and practical solution " >
>   After trying out comodo internet suite , using its defense module , one can set custom protection settings for each program.
>   I was able to immunize firefox to external windows message pumps from other processes and it worked flawlessly.
>   No application could make firefox launch websites "ie: clicking menu::about and clicking their website link doesn't open websites anymore, or any other application specific auto link launches, "like those sites that pop up after new installation or uninstallation" perfect !
>   -also there is a white list for the applications to launch links unaffected , "if you have set a general block that is"
>
> A quick tutorial on how to reach that filter window within comodo is 
>   ->main menu ->defense->advanced->computer security policy->"find all applications header entry"->click edit->click "access rights"->add firefox or iexplore exefiles into blocked tab.
>   these steps immunize that particular application against outer windows message pumps.
>
> There may be other ways to do this , but im perfectly happy with this solution .
>   Internet explorer and firefox can be immunized against unwanted external actions.

Source: [MozillaZine forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=9323265&sid=5e945d8337981a1de809813cf9084cf9#p9323265)

NOTE: In your case, you would need to create a firewall block rule for each actual uninstaller exe (as opposed to the app itself), or else just create a generic block rule that prevents anything from opening your browsers automatically.